# Same storage&IOPS, why provisioned IOPS ssd cost more than General ssd?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

From the aws ec2 CALCULATOR(http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html):

### General purpose ssd

1000G storage,
3000 IOPS,
**$97**/month

### Provisioned IOPS ssd

1000G storage,
3000 IOPS,
**$320**/month

### My questions

1. If I attach 1000G General ssd to a ec2 instance, and used 100G, what IOPS I really get? 3000 or 300?
2. If question1 is 3000, in what conditions we should use provisioned IOPS ssd, while we can increase IOPS by adding storage at lower cost?

Answer (score 0):

1. The baseline performance is 3 IOPS per GB of storage and can burst up to 3000 IOPS per volume. However the burst probably wont come into play. Since baseline for 1000GB volume is 3000 IOPS.
2. When you need more than 3000 IOPS. With provisioned you can get up to 30 IOPS per GB.

The instance size you attach these volumes to will also affect performance.

Comment: `The baseline performance is 3 IOPS per GB ` - so if my EBS is 8GB then the baseline is only 24 IOPS? Sounds very small.